# ¿Como trabajar en un archivo externo con Jquery en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

Buenas!
Estoy estudiando Programacion Web y hace tiempo que uso el editor vs code.
Cuando quiero usar `Jquery` en un archivo externo no aparece el auto-completado,no hay ayuda de sintaxis.
¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Si tu **vscode** , reconoce que el fichero que se esta trabajando es `HTML`, te lo mostrara en la esquina inferior derecha, cuando desees añadir cualquier `script` externo , escribes `script` presionas **Tab** y se te completara`<script></script>`, luego solo te queda decirle la ruta del fichero en la etiqueta:

```
<script src="/ruta/de/fichero/jquery.js"></script>
```

> El auto completado lo realiza el **vscode** mediante la tecla **Tab** o **Ctrl-Space**, y lo realiza en dependencia de el tipo de fichero que detecte, los lenguajes que les tengas instalados o exenciones

**Tab** te completara sentencias por ejemplo: **.mio>p#casa** el cual creara un `div` con clase **mio** y dentro una etiqueta `p` con **id** casa.

```
<div class="mio">
    <p id="casa"></p>
</div>
```

**Ctrl-space** te brindara sugerencias de sentencias que puedas utliziar en ese momento, por ejemplo si tecleas `console.` te mostrara como sugerencia `log`

Answer (score 1):

Basta con agregar estos Snippets, no te olvides de recargar el editor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tenes razon,lo tenia instalado y no habia leido que para usarlo tenias que teclear jq y el nombre de la funcion!
Pero cuando usas Jquery directamente en html,no hace falta,por eso mi pregunta...Aunque bueno por ahora asi me sirve,gracias!